# Built in Arguments in Custom Event

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I want to add an event to a form built in Microsoft Access 2000, I use the `[Event Procedure]` option.  Some of my events are global functions I created in VBA so that I can just enter the function name in the event property.  For instance, I have a back button on my forms that have this as their OnClick event property: `=GoBack()`.

I want to be able to use the built-in arguments in my custom functions as the event property.  For instance, the `Form_Error` event has two arguments: `DataErr` and `Response`.  In my global `=HandleFormError()`, I want to be able to set the `Response` variable.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is to do something like this

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    HandleFormError DataErr, Response
End Sub
```

and do all your logic in `HandleFormError`. There is no way to link `Form_Error` to any method other than `Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)`. This is just a VBA restriction.

For events like `Click` you can put your functions in the expression builder (makes for easier copy/pasting) but are probably just as well off doing this in a regular `Form_click` style event.

Comment: It's not the answer I wanted to read, but it is the answer.  Thank you!